# Query Taking way too long after loading the data

Tags: google-bigquery

as a normal process we just reloaded data into an existing table with "-replace" and since then the queries are taking anywhere between 5-8 minutes compare to 5-10 seconds earlier. Any help in identifying if the table needs to be either coalesced or defragmented is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post an example of your code?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How big are the files that you are loading?

Comment: Initial table size is about 45 GB and once the data reloaded it will be about 46 GB.

Comment: @TidyDev I am not sure what code example you want me to provide. This is simple select statement from the table with unnest and left joins.

Comment: Hi Santhosh, remember to add @ElliottBrossard  in a response to his comment so he gets notified. Also, showing code examples, your query and general information that you have will help us more into figuring out what's happening in your case.

Comment: I was hoping to understand how big the individual files are, rather than overall. If you are loading the data (e.g. `bq load`), it may be that a recent optimization is no longer splitting your big files, which has the effect in this case of making your queries slower. I would suggest sharing the project and table name in a bug post on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B).

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Thank you so much for the response. I have created a ticket under issue tracker and here is the ID#67890371.

Comment: @WillianFuks Willian, Thank you for the tips. I did provide the information in the Issue Tracker.